# Bounds for double exponential integrals

Tags: integration, inequality

I understand that the double-exponential integral
$$
F(a,b,C) := \int_{C}^\infty \exp(-a \exp(b x)) \, dx \quad \text{(with $a,b>0$ and $C \geq 0$)}
$$
can in general not be solved in closed-form.

I wonder wether there are 'simple expressions' in terms of $a,b,C$ as upper and lower bounds for $F(a,b,C)$ available?

Comment: I think the Ei(x) function helps you.

Comment: you may use the fact that the integral is clearly dominated from the values of $x$ near $C$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace $x$ with $\frac{y}{b}$, then $y$ with $\log z$. Then you are left with an [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), for which there are many well-known approximations, for instance [the one](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/10/) given by the Gauss continued fraction.